# VBA - Sorting Multiple Ranges on the Same Sheet By Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have code that is intended to sort dynamic ranges. The first 'With' statement sorts correctly, it is the second that I am having issues with. I am not sure how to properly identify the range I wish to sort. With the first 'With' statement, I know exactly what cell to start sorting from, A7. However, due to the dynamic nature of the data, I do not know the exact row number where the second data set will start. I am therefore trying to specify a range that starts from column A in the row that is financeTopRow, and sort to the bottom of this data.Here is my code:

```
With mainSheet.Range("A7:N" & analyticsBottomRow)
.Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns("A"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
            Key2:=.Columns("N"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
End With

With mainSheet.Range(("A" & financeTopRow), "K")
.Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns("A"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
            Key2:=.Columns("K"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
End With
```

Comment: FWIW the parameterless `.Cells` member call is redundant.

Comment: Looks like you want that second one to be `mainSheet.Range("A" & financeTopRow & ":K" & financeBottomRow)`. Consider going to these ranges and hitting Ctrl+T to format as table, then leverage the `ListObject` API so you never need to work out what the "first row" and "last row" are.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks